# Why does Direct X content for SharpDX not render when using Maximized Window mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2010, sharpdx

I am using SharpDx to render DX content to WPF application. When I set the window mode to Maximized in VS2010 the content does not show up until I manually adjust the window size. If I set the window mode to Normal in VS2010 it works fine. This happens in the SharpDX WPF sample also.

When using a maximized window mode, I can manually adjust size of window and then SharpDX content shows up.

When using a normal window, I can use the maximize button and everything works fine. This only happens when I set the window mode to Maximized inside VS2010 and try to run.

Comment: If the bug is reproduced in the sample, you should report a bug https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues

Comment: Trying to work out exactly where the problem is before I call it a bug. It seems to be the way they are using the D3DImage differently than microsoft recommends. Microsoft tutorials don't exhibit the problem. Currently working to recode their example to Microsoft recommend surface sharing technique to see if the problem is there.

Comment: I have this same problem in a program I inherited using SlimDX. Did you ever find a resolution? If so, please post it.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. My workaround was putting the WindowState in VS to Normal and directly after the Show() changing the state to Maximized again and for whatever weird reason that fixes it here.

Any real solutions are very welcome though.